# XYZ tiles not projecting correctly

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3

I have set my CRS to NAD_1983_StatePlane_Arizona_Central_FIPS_0202_Feet (ESRI:102649), the same CRS as my points. When I add the XYZ tile for Google_Imagery_Hybrid it prompts me to choose a transformation as the XYZ tile's original CRS is in EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator - Projected. I choose the first transformation option, "Inverse of Popular Visualisation Pseudo-Mercator + Inverse of NAD83 to WGS 84 (32) + NAD_1983_StatePlane_Arizona_Central_FIPS_0202_Feet", but the layer does not show up. When I zoom to the XYZ tile it doesn't seem to render at all. Is there something I am missing when it comes to transforming data layers in QGIS? Working in QGIS 3.10 A Coruna on Windows 10.

Comment: QGIS used to not ask the user to make a decision about datum transformations, which was one of the things I always preferred compared to ArcMap. I would suggest putting your project into the XYZ tile's native projection (EPSG:3857) and re-loading the XYZ layer. The layer should load without prompting you for a trans formation, which will let you make sure your points are correctly projected. If they are, then you can switch back to state plane, and try the different transformation options until you find one that works.

Comment: Or use the QuickMapServices plugin to load the google hybrid basemap. I just did that and it didn't prompt for a transformation.

Comment: I was able to load the XYZ tile in its native projection (EPSG:3857) and was able to transform my points correctly. I then tried changing my project CRS to NAD_1983_StatePlane_Arizona_Central_FIPS_0202_Feet (ESRI:102649) and the basemap disappeared. The same thing happened when I used imagery from QuickMapServices. I'd really like to keep the project CRS in State Plane and have coordinates etc. displayed in units of feet, but maybe that is not possible using the XYZ tiles or QMS base imagery.

Comment: Seems not possible also to me. The projection must not be the problem, because QGIS can reproject the tiles on the fly. The datum transformation between NAD83 and WGS84 can be a problem.